# Google Maps SDK for iOS - Polylines

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps, ios7

How to cusomize the polylines on google maps ?

Now I'm doing like in the documentation:

```
GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];
[path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.36, -122.0)];
[path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.45, -122.0)];
[path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.45, -122.2)];
[path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.36, -122.2)];
[path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.36, -122.0)];

GMSPolyline *polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
polyline.strokeColor = [UIColor greenColor];
polyline.strokeWidth = 10.f;
polyline.geodesic = YES;

polyline.map = mapView_;
```

But I need to give some effect to line (say glow effect).

How to realise this?

Thank you

Comment: could u check this to help me out  http://stackoverflow.com/q/40150430/252260

Answer (score 0):

Right now you can only set colors or gradients (transition between two colors), optionally with alpha (transparency) for polylines.
See
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/shapes#polylines

There is no glow or other effect for polylines.